# Including dependent module DLLs when building Orchard from source

Tags: orchardcms

I created a custom module that depends on a specific DLL. I used the Vandelay.Industries module as an example and followed the same approach to including external DLLs (HtmlAgilityPack in the case of Vandelay) by putting them into a folder named Libraries and pointing my references there.

Everything is working great until I go to build the project using the `ClickToBuild.cmd` script included with the Orchard source. As part of the build, my dependent DLLs in the Libraries folder of my module are not being included in the build/stage directory and my module won't work until I manually copy them over.

What is the best way to include those DLLs in my build output for the module? I'm assuming I need to adjust the Orchard.proj file but I'm not sure exactly what to do.

Comment: Are your modules included in Orchard.sln when building? I've had problems where modules not added to the sln have some of the files copied across, but not everything (namely contents of lib/, Module.txt, placement.info, and some views).

Comment: @mdm - Yes, the module is included in the solution. However, the Libraries directory is not included in the module project (at the moment). That's how Vandelay.Industries is setup as well. I've actually tried it both ways without success.

Comment: @mdm - I actually tried removing and re-adding the module project to the solution and now the build is working and my DLL ends up in the bin directory of the module. Not sure what was the problem before. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working :)